# Mips Move User Input to Specific Address

Tags: mips

I know there are easier ways to store and print an integer, but I have to do it this way for homework. I can't figure out how to store the user's input specially at 0x10010000.Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
.data
.word 0
Enter: .asciiz "Enter a number"
.globl main
.text

main:

# Ask user for number
li $v0,4 
la $a0, Enter
syscall

# User input
li $v0, 5
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a register contents onto memory you have to use `sw` instruction.
If *.data* segment is configured as usual, then it's base address is indeed `0x10010000`, so you might do this:

```
.data
store_location: .word 0
Enter: .asciiz "Enter a number"
.globl main
.text

main:

 # Ask user for number
 li $v0,4 
 la $a0, Enter
 syscall

 # User input
 li $v0, 5
 syscall
 sw $v0, store_location
```

Alternatively you can compute the target address and storing by issuing:

```
 lui $at, 0x1001  % $at now holds 0x10010000
 sw $v0, 0($at)
```